# cant kill child process

Tags: c, fork, kill

So, i have the code to the parent's process in a different file than the code of the child's process. I have to kill the child in the parent's code, but it can never get killed. Here's what i've got so far:

```
#define NO_OF_CHILDREN 3

int rtn = 1; 
for( count = 0; count < NO_OF_CHILDREN; count++ ) {

    if( rtn != 0 ) {
        rtn = fork(); 
        pid[count] = rtn;
    }   
     else {
        break;
    }
}

numKids = count;
sprintf(numeroFilhos,"%d",numKids);  

if( rtn == 0 ) {        
    execl("filho",numeroFilhos,NULL); 
}

else
{

for(i=0; i < numKids; i++)
{   
   usleep(2000000);   
   matar = kill(pidDosFilhos[i],SIGKILL);   
} 

printf("are the children dead? %d \n",matar);

} 
    exit(0);
```

I've been getting  "-1" for the return of kill... can anyone help me?

Comment: Please try to post a self-contained, minimal example. Your code is hard to follow without functions and inconsistent indentation.

Comment: When kill() returns -1, I suggest checking the value of errno to see what the error was. The perror(3) function can be useful for that.

Answer (score 0):

The children are probably dead before you get to killing them. Add a pause(); after the execl this will make the children hang until they receive *any* signal. When you kill them you still may get -1 should another process have sent a signal and unpaused one of the children